# ¿Error zoom se muestra en todos los productos y no individualmente jQuery?

Tags: jquery

El problema que presento es que al pasar por la imagen esta se activa el zoom a todos los productos de la imagen o se queda congelado la lupa al pasar sobre ella y otras, que cambios debo realizar para evitar este problema que a continuación se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el proyecto compelto: https://codepen.io/IniDesing/pen/ZEWZMmG

y, el código jQuery a continuidad:

```
$(function(){
    // code...
    var sub_width = 0;
    var sub_height = 0;
    $(".large").css("background","url('" + $(".small").attr("src") + "') no-repeat");

    $(".zoom-area").mousemove(function(e){
        var mylarge = $(this).find(".large");
        if(!sub_width && !sub_height) {
            var image_object = new Image();
            image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");
            sub_width = image_object.width;
            sub_height = image_object.height;
        } else {
            var magnify_position = $(this).offset();
            var mx = e.pageX - magnify_position.left;
            var my = e.pageY - magnify_position.top;

            if(mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0) {
                mylarge.fadeIn(100);
            } else {
                mylarge.fadeOut(100);
            }
            if(mylarge.is(":visible")){
                var rx = Math.round(mx/$(".small").width()*sub_width - mylarge.width()/2)*-1;
                var ry = Math.round(my/$(".small").height()*sub_height - mylarge.height()/2)*-1;

                var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

                var px = mx - mylarge.width()/2;
                var py = my - mylarge.height()/2;

                mylarge.css({left: px, top: py, backgroundPosition: bgp});
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Seria mucho mejor que dejaras el código en tu pregunta y no como un link de otra forma tu pregunta quedará obsoleta en el momento en que tu proyecto sea dado de baja de ese repositorio. Saludos ;)

Comment: @Israel-ICM Hola, es que me pide que agregue más detalle y no tengo más problema que especificar y no me deja publicar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo el problema esta en el evento `$(".zoom-area").mousemove`:

Cada imagen a la que se le hará zoom tiene un elemento con clase `.large`.
de esta forma cada vez que seleccionas `$('.large')` estas seleccionado todos lo elementos `.large` de todas las imágenes.

Cámbialo a `$(this).find(".large")` en cada una de las llamadas en el método para que seleccione el elemento `.large` de la imagen a la que le diste zoom.

Comparto la posible solucion:

`var mylarge = $(this).find(".large");` aquí guardas el elemento `.large` correspondiente a la imagen que le diste zoom cada vez que ocurre *mousemove*, y posteriormente llamas a esta variable dentro del método en vez de usar `$(".large")`.

```js
           $(".zoom-area").mousemove(function(e){
    var mylarge = $(this).find(".large");
            if(!sub_width && !sub_height)
            {
                var image_object = new Image();
                image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");
                sub_width = image_object.width;
                sub_height = image_object.height;
            }
            else
            {
                var magnify_position = $(this).offset();

                var mx = e.pageX - magnify_position.left;
                var my = e.pageY - magnify_position.top;
                
                if(mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0)
                {
                    mylarge.fadeIn(100);
                }
                else
                {
                    mylarge.fadeOut(100);
                }
                if(mylarge.is(":visible"))
                {
                    var rx = Math.round(mx/$(".small").width()*sub_width - mylarge.width()/2)*-1;
                    var ry = Math.round(my/$(".small").height()*sub_height - mylarge.height()/2)*-1;

                    var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";
                    
                    var px = mx - mylarge.width()/2;
                    var py = my - mylarge.height()/2;

                    mylarge.css({left: px, top: py, backgroundPosition: bgp});
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: amigo tengo el siguiente problema editado en mi pregunta, como podría corregirlo.

Comment: Amigo te sugiero declarar un solo <div class="large"></div> afuera de los <div class="zoom-area">. Posteriormente cuando ejecuta el evento asignas este div como hijo del ".zoom-area" correspondiente, por ejemplo con appendTo, y le asignas el background de la imagen <img class="small" > que estaria dentro del mismo padre ".zoom-area".